# getItemId mismatch with menu items

Tags: android, menu

I am trying to create an Android menu and using an onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) I'm trying to figure out which menu item was selected. However, my menu items are off by 1.

res/menu/settings.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menuSettings" android:title="@string/settings" />
<item android:id="@+id/menuVisit" android:title="@string/visitPopup" />
</menu>
```

And my code looks like:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Menu button click!");
Log.v(LOG_TAG, Integer.toString(item.getItemId()));
Log.v(LOG_TAG, Integer.toString(R.id.menuSettings));

switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.menuSettings:
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Trying to start Settings activity");
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
    return true;
case R.id.menuVisit:
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Trying to start menuVisit activity");
    return true;
default:
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Trying to start nondefined activity");
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

The logcat result is:

```
Menu button click
2131165200
2131165201
Trying to start nondefined activity
```

I am confused what I am doing wrong, as this piece of code did work at some time. But for unknown reasons this stopped working. As shown in the logcat output, the issue is that the 2 ID numbers do not match. They are off by one.

Answer (score 10):

Make a "Clean" and restart the app. It should regenerate the R file which obviously contains old values that are out of sync.

Comment: @Tozz
When answer works for you you should rate it: i.e. click"Up arrow" and / or accept it, i.e.  click green "Check"